# The development server returned response error code: 500, None of these files exist:

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, module

I got this error while building an app using react-native, the build was successful but got this.

[Error on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2phG1.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP268.jpg)

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./index from C:\Users\sawan\OneDrive\Desktop\React_Native/.:

None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * index\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:152:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:170:21
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1196:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:484:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:435:9)
```

I wanted to add a splash screen and an App icon in react native but ran into this error.

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty clear. Does any of the mentioned files exist?

Comment: How do I check if  they exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

None of these files exist. add file into particular path.

Comment: Could you tell me which files are to be added and where? I really didn't understand that error.